# Is there a word for start and end of a time period?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary, time

Is there a word used to describe the extremities of an arbitrary time period? The word "weekend" refers to the end of a week, but it's limited to the week and it only describes the end, but not the beginning. I'm looking for a word that means both "weekend" and "the start of the week", but isn't limited to weeks.

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding here. *Weekend* doesn't mean "the end of a week". It means the two days (Saturday and Sunday) that aren't classified as *weekdays* (the standard "working week"). The weekend is always those two days, regardless of whether you consider Saturday or Sunday to be the *last* day of the week. In my (British) experience, most businesses treat Sunday as the first day of the week, if that's a working day in their line of work.

Answer (score 5):

- *Beginning* and *end*, are the most general terminology.
- *Prologue* and *Epilogue* are literary-inspired words that have a similar meaning of bracketing the period (or story).
- If it's related to an event, you might have *setup* and *takedown* times.
- One convention for calendars is the contractions *AX* and *BX*, where *BX* is time before *before* event *X* and *AX* is time *after* the event. However, such events are usually short or marked at some overly-precise time.

  For example, the Gregorian Calendar has BC and AD, meaning *Before Christ* and *Anno Domini*, the *Year of our Lord*. Or, if you are secular or follow a different religion, BCE (Before Common Era) and CE (Common Era) are common substitutes.

  The calendar is marked in terms of the Brith of Jesus. Star Wars's Expanded Universe marks years in terms of the Battle of Yavin, as BY (Before Yavin) or AY (After Yavin).
- Sports teams will often have a *warm up* and *cool down* around working out, practicing, or playing.
- Space missions use a clock centered on the planned liftoff time, so time before that is T-x and time after that is T+x.

Do any of those fit your situation?

Comment: I'm working on code to go into a calendar program and I'm trying to refer to the first and last day of each time unit. Weekend kinda works for weeks, but only in locales where Friday through Sunday are considered to be the end and start of the week, respectively. Also, I'm looking for a single word, not a pair of words.

Comment: Not to necro, but perhaps "boundaries" would fit your situation? Also, for what it's worth, some calendars consider the weekend both the end of the week (Saturday) and the beginning of the week (Sunday).

Answer (score 0):

*period-boundary*

> - Await next backoff period boundary
> - Perform CCA on next backoff period boundary
>   *Protocols and Architectures for Wireless Sensor Networks* Holger Karl, Andreas Willig ([p.144](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=170R-1aZsQYC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=%22period%20boundary%22&source=bl&ots=rHOCBzg_c_&sig=Z1v4_wimCGfjwa0spmWsBgXVLbs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZWVmUc-KLMbsrAe0oYCgDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22period%20boundary%22&f=false))

And

> - the horizon rolls from period boundary to period boundary.
> - Move the current period to the next period boundary of interest, …
>   *Aimms Language Reference* Johannes Bisschop, Marcel Roelofs ([p.443](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=V2dCI89zHPcC&pg=PA443&lpg=PA443&dq=%22period%20boundary%22&source=bl&ots=GPHl6Bt2UP&sig=e6JrDkPOYq_a5xL-AQfs3Nr_ni4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_WNmUe23Ccm4rAe11oDgCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22period%20boundary%22&f=false))